# How to select multiple values from Database using Hibernate IN key word?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, apache-flex

I have Sample applicaion Flex+Java(using mysql database).
Actually i'm sending search result from flex to java method it is working one value.

```
for ex: we are giving flex textbox value---- "java" ------it is working fine
```

but we are giving more then two keywords `forex: java,flex`----it is not working

Here is mysql query:

```
from Course where coursename in (:name)
```

and setting parameter....

Comment: Also, I dont see a question in the description.

Comment: sorry..really i don't know this one..

Comment: Actually Flex text box have value " java,flex " but java take query like "from course where coursename in (:name)" :name=java is working but :name=java,flex not working..

Comment: What do you mean not working? Throwing an error or returning an empty result set when it should be returning some results?

Comment: yes correct it is giving null value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transform the string "java,flex" into a collection e.g. with split(',') and then feed it to the query.